# indexOf is not a function JS kata

Tags: javascript

I have this simple kata:
Given a sequence of items and a specific item in that sequence, return the item immediately following the item specified. If the item occurs more than once in a sequence, return the item after the first occurence. This should work for a sequence of any type.

My function is the following:

```
   function nextItem(xs, item) {
     for(const current of xs) {
       if(current === item) {
         const key = xs.indexOf(current); 
         return xs[key+1];
       }
     }
   }
```

Test examples:

```
Test.assertEquals(nextItem([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 5), 6);
Test.assertEquals(nextItem(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd'), undefined);
Test.assertEquals(nextItem(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c'), undefined);
Test.assertEquals(nextItem("testing", "t"), "e");
function* countFrom(n) { for (let i = n; ; ++i) yield i; }
Test.assertEquals(nextItem(countFrom(1), 12), 13);
```

Some tests pass but then I get this error:

```
TypeError: xs.indexOf is not a function
at nextItem
at /home/codewarrior/index.js:30:19
at /home/codewarrior/index.js:37:5
at Object.handleError
    <anonymous>
```

Maybe you can access directly the link:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/whats-up-next/train/javascript

Is it because indexof expects to receive a string as input? 
thanks!

Comment: Calling `nextItem` with those parameters does not result in the error you describe..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an error of `indexOf` because of the [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) use in its testing in which the item to be tested has no `indexOf`. And in this case you don't need to use an `indexOf` (although you can of course but you have to test if such function exist using `typeof`). You could use instead a flag to determine if an item is found or not. So, that when the item is found, in the next loop you have to return the current value (which is actually the next value). Check the algorithm below for guidance.

```
  found = false
  loop each item
       if (found)
           return current item
       if (current item == lookup item)
          found = true
  end loop
  return undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: xs.indexOf is not a function` means that you are calling `indexOf()` on something that is not an array. Use `console.log(xs)` right before calling `indexOf` to check what your input looks like.

Your example does not throw an error for me (leaving out the `test` part and calling `nextItem([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 5)` instead).

Comment: I might have misled you with my example, I have it just to give you an idea about the expected result. I added some more now, but actually on the codewar site they don't show you the test that failed. Maybe you are right, there is probably a test where the function receive as input something different than string/array.

Answer (score -1):

The values provided by the test seems that they are something other than `array` or `string`. You might use an algorithm which doesnot need `indexOf()` like below

```
function nextItem(xs, item) {
  let check = false;
  for(let i of xs){
    if(check === true) return i
    if(item === i) check = true;
  }
}
```